# Apple iOS App Distribution to Corporate / BYOD (Devices) via Apple Business Manager or Other

Tags: ios

I need to distribute an Apple iOS app which has been developed internally to the phones of our employees via "Private App Store". Is there a way?

Our app was rejected on the public app store. We were also rejected from Enterprise Program. Ad-hoc is very complicated as requires UDID of each phone.

We were advised to go via Apple Business Manager. The thing is that ABM does not distribute apps. Apple is not able to provide adequate support. They could not answer my question and just keep rejecting our app and advising us ABM that in my opinion will not help us in no way as employees use their personal phones. Last agent told me that distribution is done via MDM software.

Comment: I recently made an app for our company ipads, so slightly different.  I had to register with ABM, get an MDM set up to distribute, and use app store connect.  Registering devices with MDM should  be as simple as scanning a QR code.  It takes some effort to set it all up, and there is a bit of a learning curve, but it's worth the effort, as now I can update all devices remotely.  Apple support was very helpful & responsive.

Comment: [fastlane](https://fastlane.tools/) [fir](https://fir.im/) may be helpful

Comment: Thank you for reply. I've done exactly the same procedure today. The only negative is that MDM costs some money per device per month. I use jamfNow, feature to enroll called Open Enrollment.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible!
App should be published under Apple Developer license on a public App Store but for private distribution.
Before sending to review I enrolled into Apple Business Manager under new Apple ID.
In Pricing and Availability section I designated this app via organization ID to the Apple Business manager account created before (3rd option). Also had to accept agreement for paid apps inside AppStore connect account in order make this 3rd option tickable.
Also had to enable Custom Apps inside ABM account. My app appeared in ABM several hours later after Apple approval.
I picked option to buy licenses as Redemption codes (instead of MDM). Then Download button appeared on the right. I downloaded xls file with codes and links.
I sent links to employees. App installs without any questions by link. Also their is option to manually enter redemption code in the App Store app on the phone and the app installs as from public App Store.

Comment: Another problem here. Apple never says about it. Custom app cannot be updated automatically as public app. Custom app must be deleted manually from iphone and then reinstalled from settings of the Apple Store app. (Apple confirmed it by email) It does not make any sense!!! Solution is MDM, but. 1. Not all MDMs can do it. 2. MDM that supports updating of the custom apps cost at least 4$ per month per device!