# Apple iOS App distribution to company staff with their own device via ABM (Custom app option)

Tags: ios

I am planning to use custom app (in Apple Store) option to distribute an app to our company staff with their own phones. (similar to what Roland is talking about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58598037/apple-ios-app-distribution-to-corporate-byod-devices-via-apple-business-mana#))

But am unsure of following:

1) if the custom app option with redemption code is the correct approach for the above case?

2) do we need separate account for Apple Store Connect portal and ABM portal? if yes, how will the app appear on ABM portal once it is approved?

3) do we need to enable custom app option under ABM portal in this scenario?

4) is it true - custom app cant be updated ? does it mean we can't publish new changes to app ?

Please advise.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you are using a B2B app then you really should be using an MDM to distribute the apps to the devices. It will make it much easier to distribute the apps and distribute updates. iOS 13 now has partitioning for BYO devices where you can use a managed Apple ID for the corporate data and apps without impacting the users personal data and apps. When the MDM issues a "wipe" command it only removes corporate data and apps,  not personal data and apps

Comment: For question 2, your App Store connect login is related to your developer program membership, which is separate from ABM. You get your organisation id from ABM and then enter that id in App Store Connect.  you can then "purchase" the app in ABM. 3. Yes. 4. I can't speak from personal experience because we use an MDM,  but anecdotally people do report problems with updates when using redemption codes.

Comment: @Paulw11 - thanks for responding. I thought MDM should be used when staff is using companys phone. isn't it true? 

this is not B2B scenario, am trying to publish an app which will be private to company so only companys staff can use it. I read few articles where custom app option was suggested. (i.e. https://www.goodbarber.com/blog/distributing-your-ios-app-with-custom-apps-a979/?preview=1)

you mentioned "purchase the app " - what's that? do i need to pay for getting redemption codes?

Comment: I would suggest that an MDM should be used any time you have company data on a device.  You should definitely use an MDM for corporate devices and with the new partitioning available I would also say you should use it for personal devices with company data.  B2B is the old name for private/custom VPP apps - It is just quicker to type.  Now the company supplying the app and the company consuming the app can be the same organisation, so the term B2B isn't accurate any more.  The "purchase" can be free, that is just the term that is used to acquire the app through ABM

Comment: If you don't use an MDM then you have to keep track of issuing redemption codes (each code can only be used once) and you have no way of removing the app if the employee leaves

Comment: thanks @Paulw11 - the app doesnt contain company data so am thinking to try redemption code option but i am concerned about following 

1. do i need to pay extra $ to get redemption codes?
2. once i get redemption code, how do i distribute app among staff?
3. what happens when new staff join the company and he/she wants to use the app?

Comment: do you know anything about above questions? i couldnt find any references on internet.

Comment: No, you don't pay for redemption codes.  When you publish an app as a private app you assign a price tier.  If the price tier is free then nothing is charged.  With private apps it is OK for a developer to receive payment outside the App Store.  Since your company would be both developer and purchaser there is no payment anyway. 2. You have to figure that out.  You can use email, you could load them into some sort of database and create an automated way of staff requesting a code. 3. As for 2, you need to send them an unused code

Comment: Thank you @Paulw11 - I have started playing with app store custom app option, will let you know how I go. Meanwhile I've been told to look similar thing on google side too, and i've started following this - https://support.google.com/a/answer/2494992?hl=en

What i don't understand here is distribution part - how will that work ? Have you published private app on google play store before ? 

Thank you.

Comment: I haven't done this for Android, but I think the instructions you linked to are only relevant if you are using Google management for your devices.  If you are using a different MDM then I think you can publish the APK directly through the MDM e.g. http://mi.extendedhelp.mobileiron.com/60/all/en/Content/App_Catalog.htm If you aren't using an MDM then you will need to work out some way of distributing the APK directly to users

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11 for your response. we aren't using MDM and am not sure how google management will work when employees gonna use their own mobile. I found couple of more options too, 1) https://support.google.com/googleplay/work/answer/9495634?hl=en 2) “Closed Track” option in Google Play store (https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en)

Comment: Google management is just their cloud-based MDM.  EMM is another name for MDM (Enterprise Mobile Management vs Mobile Device Management).  You could use the closed track test option, but I have no idea on how long a test can run for.  I know with Apple's TestFlight builds expire after 90 days.

Comment: ah alright if there is an expiry then it won't work. The problem is there is no blog/website which talks about pre-requisites or distribution part in detail. So its hard to understand which approach will work best. @Paulw11